# Wordpress: Dynamically query/filter posts by taxonomy term_id

Tags: taxonomy, wordpress

I have a walker to display terms of a taxonomy (see post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732017/wordpress-hierarchical-list-of-taxonomy-terms)). It's a hierarchical list that is 3 levels deep:

Taxonomy

1. terms (number of posts incl. all sub levels)

   1.1. subterms (number of posts incl. subsubterms 1 & 2)

   1.1.1. subsubterms (number of posts)

   - display post with Category "Subsubterms"

   1.1.2 subsubterms (number of posts)

   - display post with Category "Subsubterms"

The terms display fine, but the posts on subsubterm-level do not display. 
The following code only displays post from the "Uncategorized" category.

```
add_filter( 'XYZ_index', 'return_XYZ_index' );

function return_XYZ_index()
{

  $taxonomies = array( 
    'XYZ'
  );

  $args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'name', 
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'        => false,
    'fields'            => 'all',
    'parent'            => 0,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'child_of'          => 0,
    'pad_counts'        => false,
    'cache_domain'      => 'core'
  );

  $terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);    

  $return .= '<ul>';     

  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        $subterms = get_terms($taxonomies, array(
          'parent'   => $term->term_id,
          'hide_empty' => false
          ));

        //count posts in terms plus subterms
          $count = 0;
          $countargs = array(
            'child_of' => $term->term_ID,
            );
          $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomies,$countargs);
          foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
            $count +=$tax_term->count;
            }

      // return terms 
      $return .= sprintf(
        '<li id="category-%1$s" class="toggle">%2$s  <span class="post-count">' . $count . '</span><span class="cat-description">%3$s</span>',       
        $term->term_id,
        $term->name,
        $term->description
      );

      //count posts in subterm
      $countsub = 0;
      $countsubargs = array(
        'child_of' => $subterm->term_id,
        );
      $tax_term_subs = get_terms($taxonomies, $countsubargs);
      foreach ($tax_term_subs as $tax_term_sub) {
        $countsub +=$tax_term_sub->count;
      }


        $return .= '<ul>';

        foreach ( $subterms as $subterm ) {

          $subsubterms = get_terms($taxonomies, array(
            'parent'   => $subterm->term_id,
            'hide_empty' => false
            ));            

          // return subterms
          $return .= sprintf(
          '<li id="category-%1$s" class="toggle">%2$s  <span class="post-count">' . $countsub . '</span><span class="cat-description">%3$s</span>',       
          $subterm->term_id,
          $subterm->name,
          $subterm->description
          );

          $return .= '<ul>';

          foreach ( $subsubterms as $subsubterm ) {

            // return subsubterms
            $return .= sprintf(
            '<li id="category-%1$s" class="toggle">%2$s <span class="post-count">%3$s</span><span class="cat-description">%4$s</span>',       
            $subsubterm->term_id,
            $subsubterm->name,
            $subsubterm->count,
            $subsubterm->description
            );

            // return posts (**EDITED CODE**)

            $postargs = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                'taxonomy' =>'XYZ,
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' =>  $subsubterm->term_id
                )
              )
            );
            $post_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
             if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : 
                $return .= '<ul>';
                 while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post();
                    $return .= '<li><a class="link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>' . "\n";
                endwhile;
                $return .= '</ul>';

             wp_reset_postdata();
             else:
             endif;

            $return .= '</li>'; //end subsubterms li
          }

          $return .= '</ul>'; //end subsubterms ul

        $return .= '</li>'; //end subterms li 
        }            

        $return .= '</ul>'; //end subterms ul

      $return .= '</li>'; //end terms li
    } //end foreach term        

    $return .= '</ul>';

  return $return;
}
```

I'm not sure if this part is even possible:

```
'term' => $subsubterm->term_id
```

Thanks!

Comment: please provide whole code so can check

Comment: Complete code added, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace category with your actual taxonomy.
Use following code:

```
          $args = array(
              'tax_query' => array(
              array(
              'taxonomy' =>'category',
              'field' => 'id',
              'terms' =>  $subsubterm->term_id
              )
            )
      );
$post_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
 if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $return .= '<ul>';
     while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post();
        $return .= '<li><a class="link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>' . "\n";
    endwhile;
    $return .= '</ul>';

 wp_reset_postdata();
else:
 endif;
```

Or you can use complete code provided below:

```
function return_XYZ_index()
{

  $taxonomies = array( 
    'XYZ'
  );

  $args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'name', 
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'        => false,
    'fields'            => 'all',
    'parent'            => 0,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'child_of'          => 0,
    'pad_counts'        => false,
    'cache_domain'      => 'core'
  );

  $terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);

  $return .= '<ul>'; 

  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        $subterms = get_terms($taxonomies, array(
          'parent'   => $term->term_id,
          'hide_empty' => false
          ));

        //count posts in terms plus subterms
          $count = 0;
          $countargs = array(
            'child_of' => $term->term_ID,
            );
          $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomies,$countargs);
          foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
            $count +=$tax_term->count;
            }

      // return terms 
      $return .= sprintf(
        '<li id="category-%1$s" class="toggle">%2$s  <span class="post-count">' . $count . '</span><span class="cat-description">%3$s</span>',       
        $term->term_id,
        $term->name,
        $term->description
      );

      //count posts in subterm
      $countsub = 0;
      $countsubargs = array(
        'child_of' => $subterm->term_id,
        );
      $tax_term_subs = get_terms($taxonomies, $countsubargs);
      foreach ($tax_term_subs as $tax_term_sub) {
        $countsub +=$tax_term_sub->count;
      }


        $return .= '<ul>';

        foreach ( $subterms as $subterm ) {

          $subsubterms = get_terms($taxonomies, array(
            'parent'   => $subterm->term_id,
            'hide_empty' => false
            ));            

          // return subterms
          $return .= sprintf(
          '<li id="category-%1$s" class="toggle">%2$s  <span class="post-count">' . $countsub . '</span><span class="cat-description">%3$s</span>',       
          $subterm->term_id,
          $subterm->name,
          $subterm->description
          );

          $return .= '<ul>';

          foreach ( $subsubterms as $subsubterm ) {

            // return subsubterms
            $return .= sprintf(
            '<li id="category-%1$s" class="toggle">%2$s <span class="post-count">%3$s</span><span class="cat-description">%4$s</span>',       
            $subsubterm->term_id,
            $subsubterm->name,
            $subsubterm->count,
            $subsubterm->description
            );

            // return posts
             $args = array(
                  'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                  'taxonomy' =>'category',
                  'field' => 'id',
                  'terms' =>  $subsubterm->term_id
                  )
                )
          );
    $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );  if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : 
              $return .= '<ul>';
              while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); 
                $return .= '<li><a class="link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>' . "\n";
              endwhile;
              $return .= '</ul>';

              wp_reset_postdata();

            else:
            endif;

            $return .= '</li>'; //end subsubterms li
          }

          $return .= '</ul>'; //end subsubterms ul

        $return .= '</li>'; //end subterms li 
        }            

        $return .= '</ul>'; //end subterms ul

      $return .= '</li>'; //end terms li
    } //end foreach term        

    $return .= '</ul>';

  return $return;
}
```

Comment: THAT DID IT! I guess it's time for me to move on and do something else ;-) I implemented your code piece and it didn't work. Then I used your complete code and - Tadaa - here it is: the posts for each subsubterm. Must have a typo somewhere. Anyway, I can't thank you enough!!!

Comment: Unfortunately the counting is off. The idea is to count posts in each level including its sub levels. The number of posts in subsubterms is correct, but on subterm level and term level, posts from _all_ terms are counted.

Comment: what you want to get? count or list of posts?

Comment: Count only. Posts are only displayed on subsubterm level, but each level shall display the number of posts (including posts on its sub levels)

Comment: I edited the list in the initial post to better describe it (counting is in brackets ().